# Robocopy 3.1...not accepting my target destination

Tags: windows-7, robocopy

When I enter my source and destination locations, Robocopy puts my source and destination on the same line. The log says that no destination directory is specified but I specify it in the GUI. I thought permissions were a factor so I added myself to the local Admin's group. Both source and destination are "local" drives but both are "external drives" connected via USB. I have copied files using Robocopy multiple times to this destination but have not been able from this source.

Comment: Please write out the robocopy command you are entering so that we can see where this is going wrong.

Comment: As you are using the GUI please provide a screenshot.

Comment: Upload the screenshots to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.